# select count and other records in one single query

Tags: select, mysql, count

I have the following query

```
select main_cat_name,cat_url from mf_main order by main_cat_name
```

This returns whole data of my table.Now i want to have count of the total rows of this table.I can do it using another query but how can i use them in one single query???

I want two data ONE :- the rows of the table TWO:- the count
how can i have that in one single query

I tried this but it gives correct count but displays only first row of the table :

```
select count(cat_id),main_cat_name,cat_url from mf_main order by main_cat_name
```

Comment: if you're dealing with php, it does the job for you ..

Comment: no even in php its no doing what i want :-(

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try with Group By like:

```
SELECT count(cat_id), main_cat_name, cat_url FROM mf_main GROUP BY main_cat_name, cat_url ORDER BY main_cat_name
```

Right solution i hope:

This is what you want:)

```
SELECT x.countt, main_cat_name, cat_url FROM mf_main, (select count(*) as countt FROM mf_main) as x ORDER BY main_cat_name
```

If you use mysql u have "as" like i did. For others db may be without as (like oracle)

Answer (score 19):

You could try

```
select main_cat_name,cat_url,
COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_count
from mf_main
order by main_cat_name
```

Not sure if MySQL accepts the `AS`, just remove it if it does not.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(cat_id), main_cat_name, cat_url 
from mf_main
group by main_cat_name, cat_url
order by main_cat_name
```

Comment: this is giving count 1 for every cat_name

Answer (score 1):

Once you already created a select statement

there is already a num_rows record of your count as num_rows

Answer (score -1):

If you don't use WHERE query and don't limit the output any other way, like using GROUP BY, than the rows amount in result will match the rows amount in table, so you can use database driver specific methods to find the rows count, e.g. [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) in PHP